# Loop Vue2 tag with keyup + modifier and click

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have following code but wonder if I can loop it instead of copy-pasting.

**calculator.ts**

```
data: function() {
  return {
    calcInput: 'user types some value in input with v-model'
  }
},
template: `
  <span
    class="calc-button-control"
    @click="evaluate()"
    @keyup.enter="evaluate()"
  >calc</span>

  <span
    class="calc-button-control"
    @click="calcInput = calcInput.substring(0, calcInput.length - 1) "
    @keyup.del="calcInput = calcInput.substring(0, calcInput.length - 1) "
  >del</span>

  <span
    class="calc-button-control"
    @click="calcInput = ''"
    @keyup.esc="calcInput = ''"
  >clr</span>
`
```

Pass modifier to v-on:keyup is the hardest part here.
`@[loopedItem.key]={loopedItem.method}` - doesn't work.
In this case I can see in event listeners for example `keyup.enter` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please state (maybe upfront) whether the code works, and just the coding alternatives listed close to the bottom didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Or well, maybe you *could* but I absolutely do not see any reason to do so.

What each `<span>` has in common:

- The same class
- They all have *a* click event and *a* keyup event

What each `<span>` has different:

- They all have different handlers for what to do on the click/keyup event
- They all have listen for different keyup events.

I don't see any benefit in creating a loop from this.

Some things you *might* want to consider though is:

- Have a method that is performed for both click and the keyup event, to not copy-paste code between the different handlers.
- Create a component for `<span class="calc-button-control">`

If you have plenty of more of these `<span>` elements, creating a component would be the way to go. Then you could have a component to handle the following:

- It is a `<span>` element and applies the `calc-button-control` class.
- It has a method for what to do when clicked or keyup event triggers.

I am not sure how flexible you can make the `keyup` listener, I don't think you can for example pass `:keypress="enter"` or similar to have it listen to `@keyup.enter` so I am not sure if creating a component for all of this does more harm than good.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Image the application, where you type a text from the screen (blind keyboard writing) and there will be a keyboard with all letters like on keyboard. When user types a letter, js have to listen for key press and set some animation class to that key. So I have to hard code it?